# Azure Synapse Analytics - deleting pipeline Folder

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am new to Synapse and I have to make a pipeline that will delete files from folders in a hierarchy like the attached image. [expecting hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qALT.png).  The red half circles mark the files I would like to delete files for example older than 2 months.

As for now I have made a pipline for a single folder and using the for each loop I can get to the files and delete the corresponding one. And it works, since I have about 60-70 folders and even more files I wanted to go a level higher up  and make a pipeline for each folder to execute. And with this is a problem. When i use GetMetadata Activity for top folder, and use for each loop to take name folders then i can not acess files in folder just only folder. Could you help me someone how to slove this?

[deleting pipline for single folder using for each loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNPzK.png)

Comment: Will you be deleting only one file from each folder with same file name? Or can there be multiple files that you want to delete (can there be multiple files older than 2 months)

Comment: Multiple files with diffrent names only sort by date.

Comment: Can you please confirm this, you want to keep current month (09) and previous month(08) files only and delete the rest. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, i would like keeping recent data, last two months.

Comment: But my problem is with  subfolders. When I use GetMetadata Activity I have 2 scenarios. 
1) name folders -> for each loop for folders -  I can not go into delete activity with the name of folder :/. Only with the name of the files.
2) I can take all files using parameter ** for folder patch and have access to all files but it fails later on deleting because can not recognize form what folder was specific file was.

Comment: The requirement might require using a nested for loop. Is there any specific reason that you can't/should not use this approach?

Comment: You can't nest a ForEach loop inside another ForEach loop. That is the problem.

Comment: It is reference to use execute another pipeline. But i dont know how to pass subfolders path as reference to new pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using nested `for each` activities with the help of `execute pipeline` activity. As mentioned, `Get metadata` with wildcards returns all files without folders and `Delete` activity is unable to recognize wildcard folder paths(Folder/*).

- I have created a similar folder structure for demo. In my pipeline, I have first created an array parameter `req_files` (sample1.csv and sample2.csv) with names of files required.

[image]

**Note:** If you want to dynamically do this, you can use `append variable` to build required file names (file09/22 and file08/22).

- I used one `get metadata` to get folder names (which are inside root folder). I am iterating through the output of get metadata in my `for each` activity (items value is `@activity('root folder contents').output.childItems`).
- Inside my for each, I used another `get metadata` activity to loop through each of the sub folders (to get file contents).
- Now I have the folder name and list of files inside it. I am going to **use `execute pipeline` to implement nested for each**. Create 3 parameters in a new pipeline called `delete_pipeline` (where I perform delete) as `current_folder, folder_files and  files_needed`.
- Pass the following dynamic content for each of them from parent pipeline.

```
current_folder: @item().name
folder_files: @activity('sub folder contents').output.childItems
files_needed: @pipeline().parameters.req_files
```

[image]

- Now in `delete_pipeline`, I have a for each loop to loop through the list of files we are passing (items value is `@pipeline().parameters.folder_files`).
- Inside this for each, I am using an `If condition` activity. This is because I want to delete files which are not in my `req_files` parameter (array from parent pipeline which we passed to `files_needed` parameter in `delete_pipeline`). The condition for `if condition` activity will be as following:

```
@contains(pipeline().parameters.files_needed,item().name)
```

[image]

- We need to delete the file only when it is not present in `req_files (files_needed)`. So, when the condition is false, we perform delete.
- I have created 2 parameters `file_namepath_of_file_to_delete` and `file_name_to_delete` in the dataset I am using for delete activity with following dynamic content.

```
file_namepath_of_file_to_delete: Folder/@{pipeline().parameters.current_folder}
file_name_to_delete: @item().name
```

[image]

When I run the pipeline, it keeps the required files and deletes the rest. The following are output images for reference.

- Debug output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyggK.png
- My folder after I run the pipeline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x4Vd.png

Comment: Thank you so much! With your demo and help I solved my problem!